# Cant rename rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to rename a few of my routes, for example:

```
  get 'legal/terms_of_service', :to => 'legal#terms_of_service', :as => :datenschutz
```

that works, but it doesn't change the acutal URI- and I want that to be changed as well. path: does not work here.

Thank you

Comment: What do you want the URI to be?

Comment: datenschutz would be an option. I just want to understand how it should be done, I might need to do this to other routes as well

Comment: Do you mean something like `get :datenschutz, to: 'legal#terms_of_service'`?

Comment: As @jvillian asked, what do you want your url to be, exactly?....`/datenschutz` or `/datenschutz/terms_of_service`or `/legal/datenschutz` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the URI to be `/datenshutz` then you can do this:

```
get '/datenschutz', :to => 'legal#terms_of_service', :as => :datenschutz
```

The `get '/datenschutz'` determines the url browsers or other http clients use to access the controller.

The `:to => 'legal#terms_of_service'` specifies a controller class and controller action used to respond to the route.

The `:as => :datenschutz` changes the method you use in views to create links to the route (such as `datenschutz_path`).